# Let $c>0$ and let $ X\sim U(-c,c) $. How to find $c$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $c>0$ and let $ X\sim U(-c,c) $.

I don't understand how to use the fact $P(|x|\leq 1 ) = 2P(|x|\geq1)$ to find $c$.

Comment: Hint: draw a graph of the density function (for several $c$) and see how the given fact relates to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $P(|X|\le 1)+P(|X|\ge 1)=1\implies P(|X|\le 1)=2/3=\int_{-1}^1\frac1{2c}dx$.